# Cabal: Does not exists message in windows 7

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I try to update cabal, I get this.

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cabal-install-1.22.0.0...
cabal: does not exist
Failed to install cabal-install-1.22.0.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-install-1.22.0.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Content of my PATH variable is

```
C:\Users\.....\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin;C:\opt\gtk\bin
```

What to do now?

EDIT: It's not only problem of cabal-install it's a problem of all packages ...

EDIT: My username not include any spaces

Comment: a) don't update cabal on windows via that - use a separate binary downloaded from cabal website, run that instead in its own folder and update the global instance
b) use `-v`

Comment: Does your username include any spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Everithing is right now. I removed Mingw which I have installed previousli. GHC uses LD which isn't come with it, and that's caused that error.